# Passing a 2-dimensional character array to a function

Tags: c, arrays

I am trying to create a program to take 2-dimensional array and print each line out by its own (if you have ever took the Python course in Codecademy, it's like the battleship lesson and I'm trying to print out the board).  I've done numerous google searches but two-dimensional character arrays doesn't seem to be covered very well on the internet

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

const int n = 5;
void printgraph(char *graph[]) {
    printf("\nPrinting graph:\n\n");
    int i = 0;
    for(i = 0; i <= 5 - 1; i++) {   // this is only a temporary solution
        printf("i %i | %s\n", i, &graph[i]);    // error here
    }
}

    int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char array[5][6];    // defining the char array here
    strcpy(array[0], "abcde");
    strcpy(array[1], "fghij");
    strcpy(array[2], "klmno");
    strcpy(array[3], "pqrst");
    strcpy(array[4], "uvwxy");
 printf("array: %s\n", array[1]);   // it prints out perfectly within the function itself
    printgraph(*array);    // error here
    return 0;
}
```

This is what terminal tells me

```
$cc -g -Wall ex3.c -o ex3
ex3.c: In function ‘printgraph’:
ex3.c:11:3: warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 3 has type ‘char **’ [-Wformat=]
   printf("i %i | %s\n", i, &graph[i]);
   ^
ex3.c: In function ‘main’:
ex3.c:23:2: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘printgraph’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
  printgraph(*array);
  ^
ex3.c:6:6: note: expected ‘char **’ but argument is of type ‘char *’
 void printgraph(char *graph[]) {
      ^
$./ex3
array: fghij

Printing graph:

i 0 | abcde
i 1 | hij
i 2 | o
i 3 | uvwxy
i 4 |
```

As you can see, not all arrays are printed out correctly.  I've tried different variations taking out pointers, but this one is the only one that works halfway decently

Comment: use `graph[i]` instead of `&graph[i]` in `printf`.

Comment: When I do that I get "Segmentation fault (core dumped)"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not just pass the whole array to the function and print out the required stuff inside the function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

const int n = 5;
void printgraph(char graph[][6]) { /* ---> Changes made here */
    printf("\nPrinting graph:\n\n");
    int i = 0;
    for(i = 0; i <= 5 - 1; i++) {   
        printf("i %i | %s\n", i, graph[i]);   /* Check the changes here */
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
char array[5][6];    // defining the char array here
strcpy(array[0], "abcde");
strcpy(array[1], "fghij");
strcpy(array[2], "klmno");
strcpy(array[3], "pqrst");
strcpy(array[4], "uvwxy");
printgraph(array);    /* Pass the array to the function */
return 0;
}
```

Comment: For some reason when I directly copy+paste that into gedit it works perfectly but I can't find what you did differently besides "void printgraph(char graph[][6]) {"... thanks a lot, I'll take a look at this code!

Answer (score 1):

A simple workaround could be to declare a double pointer of `char` as your array in `main()` and pass the double pointer to the `printgraph()` function.

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

const int n = 5;
void printgraph(char **graph) {
    printf("\nPrinting graph:\n\n");
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {   // this is only a temporary solution
        printf("i %i | %s\n", i, graph[i]);   
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char *array[5];
    for(int i=0;i<5;++i)
        array[i] = malloc(6);

    strcpy(array[0], "abcde");
    strcpy(array[1], "fghij");
    strcpy(array[2], "klmno");
    strcpy(array[3], "pqrst");
    strcpy(array[4], "uvwxy");
    printf("array: %s\n", array[1]);    

    printgraph(array); 

    for(int i=0;i<5;++i)
        free(array[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `array` itself doesn't need to be malloc'd, only the `array[i]` entries in this approach. Also, `malloc(6)` is simpler than having all the casts and sizeofs and guff.

Comment: I'm sorry, I did not understand this approach. It would be better if you can please edit my code with your idea. :)

Comment: OK, edited. OP will want to consider adding a parameter to `printgraph`, or a sentinel value to the end of the list of pointers, instead of hardcoding `5` or having global variable.

Answer (score 0):

As you are passing one time dereferenced array as argument (i.e. address of first array) you can able to print only first array.

You can see below where, we can make use of pointer to array of 6 elements to collect address of 2D array where, each 1D array has 6 elements.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

const int n = 5;
void printgraph(char (*graph)[6]) //pointer to array of 6 elements//
    {
        printf("\nPrinting graph:\n\n");
        int i = 0;
        for(i = 0; i <= 5 - 1; i++) {   // this is only a temporary solution
            printf("i %i | %s\n", i, graph[i]);    // error here
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char array[5][6];    // defining the char array here
    printf("%u\n",array);
    printf("%u\n",&array);
    strcpy(array[0], "abcde");
    strcpy(array[1], "fghij");
    strcpy(array[2], "klmno");
    strcpy(array[3], "pqrst");
    strcpy(array[4], "uvwxy");
    printf("array: %s\n", array[1]);   // it prints out perfectly within the function itself
    printgraph(array);    // error here
    return 0;
}
```

Find the output:

```
array: fghij

Printing graph:

i 0 | abcde
i 1 | fghij
i 2 | klmno
i 3 | pqrst
i 4 | uvwxy
```